# Accidentally shorted laptop's usb with 12v external supply

Tags: laptop, usb, power-supply, burning, physical-damage

I was working with Lcd Cfl inverter, which works on 12v supply. To provide a pwm signal i wanted use 5v signal which at that moment i tried to provide from my laptop, ik i was being stupid. So i was working free hand with that and i accidentally touched usb's 5v (for split seconds) with another wire from inverter which was carrying 12v(not Vin). Laptop went off immediately. At this point i think its right to mention that my laptop has reverse current protection since it happened to me earlier and it took the hit quite nice and worked fine after that (took 15 min cool down). So i gaved my laptop 15 min rest. Now it boot up properly, but its freezes at loading that comes before windows logo , windows bootable usb loading , and automated recovery loading screen( see pic for clearity). I can go into bios, bios is working fine , can see all details nice and clean regarding cpu, ram etc. But can't get past the bios .
Anybody have any idea is to what could have fried inside after that 12v input to usb?
The laptop is Asus ROG GL553 VD.[freeze screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV1L0.jpg)
[uefi/bios screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIVnj.jpg)

Edit 1:
Showed my laptop to asus, their policy dont include repairs so they only can replace mobo for which they ask 770 usd or 57k Rs (lmfao). Also showed to some repair center with good repo but they also couldn't find whats wrong, so they returned it -_- .

Edit 2:
I think south bridge is fried since its overheating, that would explain why laptop won't get past bios. Had to check myself since all these laptop repair services are useless in my city. My main motive to post this was just to let others know what could go wrong in such situation, already knew laptop is bricked from beginning. Hope this helps someone in some way.

Comment: great asus bios usually have the ability to control individual usb ports, try disabling the effected USB port in the BIOS to see if that helps.

Comment: So i tried what you said , i didn't find any option to do so. However i tried disabling any option saying usb, searched the same thing on Google but didn't find so i had to try something. Tried booting up again but no luck. Same issue freezing at that loading circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fried the USB controller. No doubt about it.
You admitted this was the second time. You have probably blown or partially damaged some internal safety fuses on the first time already. The second time there wasn't enough protection left and the laptop sustained fatal damage.

That you can still get into the Bios doesn't mean anything.
It is possible to be able to get into the Bios (even using a USB keyboard in some cases) with a partially damaged USB controller.
The Bios does only very limited initialization and error-checking on the USB.
It may not notice there is a problem.
But the full OS with the full driver-suite (Windows started from the HDD/SDD or another boot-medium) will get weird/bad values from the USB controller which may cause the driver to crash or just act very strangely.

Normally a single driver failing doesn't bring down Windows (unless it is the SATA or NVMe driver controlling the system-drive).
But there is this little quirk in Windows: Any bus-interface (USB, but also FireWire and ThunderBolt) that supports storage media (e.g. USB sticks and USB harddrives) also has a direct interface with the Windows storage drivers and may crash those storage drivers as a side-effect if something really weird happens with the bus.
If that happens your system will freeze up completely because Windows can't access the system-drive and/or the pagefile anymore.
Under normal conditions this never happens, but when your hardware is flaky...

You might be able to use the laptop (without USB) if you can completely disable the USB controller in the Bios, but most computers don't provide that option in the Bios.
Even if you can do that you have to realize that the hardware is damaged and the damage may get progressively worse with continued use. There is no telling what else is going to fail later...

The USB controller in just about every modern laptop motherboard is part of the main motherboard chipset and is extremely hard to replace.
It takes a specialist with high-end equipment to do this. And there is no guarantee of success because you can't tell from the outside if it is only the chip that got fried or if there is other electronic damage as well.

Replacing the motherboard, or the whole laptop, will be easier and cheaper.

Comment: I think I have a rough idea of what's fried. The South bridge is overheating, that would even explain why laptop can't get past bios in any case. Replacing motherboard is grossly expensive I would rather buy msi with same spec in same price asus would replace mobo. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @CoderX  Southbridge would be the logical place for the USB controller to be on most chipsets that have a separate Southbridge. And overheating is certainly a sign something is really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Laptop went off immediately. At this point i think its right to
> mention that my laptop has reverse current protection
>
> i gave my laptop 15 min rest. Now it boot up properly, but its freezes
> at loading that comes before windows logo , windows bootable usb
> loading , and automated recovery loading screen( see pic for clarity).
>
> I can go into bios, bios is working fine , can see all details nice
> and clean regarding cpu, ram etc. But can't get past the bios .

Your computer appears to be fine (great):  Starts, boots, Video working.

So it now appears you must allow the Automatic Recovery to proceed. It may allow you to save you data. Watch the prompts carefully.

If Automatic Recovery fails, you need to reinstall Windows.

There is some chance the drive was damaged, but it is worth trying to recover.

If you can remove the drive, it will be worth trying to recover data that way.

If none of the above then the motherboard is likely damaged in some way.

Comment: As i mentioned above it freezes at loading even automatic recovery or windows usb , regarding data also i had stored all windows essential stuff in ssd and all my data in hdd so i think my data is safe with hdd and all i need is to remove that and place it in other pc. But i am wondering what component failure could result this way.

Comment: Do you have other USB ports to try?  Pity if the USB ports were fried during the wrong application of voltage.

Comment: Also, can you try installing Windows on a different drive?

Comment: Yes , i tried windows usb on different usb port, and as for installation on different drive , i can't get past the loading circle in any case. I mean if usb ports were fried it shouldn't make the laptop freeze at loading right?

Comment: I am not sure what else might be wrong, so it seems like some issue on the motherboard.